# Discord.js crash upon command "Uncaught TypeError"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Hello Im and new to coding and working on a Bot command where it takes user input and saves it to a text file. But upon loading it states "Uncaught *TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of null"*

Some changers I've made looking at various things:

> application = collected.array()[0]**.content;**
> when .content was there it would at least run a few times then crash with *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘content’ of undefined*

> *let appString = "" + application* originally was using toString() function

> fs.appendFile(`./see/letters(${fileSearch}).txt`, appString + "\n", function (err) added $fileSearch because I thought having to many users saving to my local computer file was overwhelming it

Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated as each thing I try keeps crashing it but all seem to be some Uncaught TypeError

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ocean',
    description: 'Takes User Input and saves it as Text file letters.txt',
    execute(message, args) {
      let application = {}
      let filter = (message) => !message.author.bot;
      let options = {
        max: 1,
        time: 15000
      };
      message.member.send("Write something")
      .then(dm => {
        // After each question, we'll setup a collector on the DM channel
        return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
      })
      .then(collected => {
        // Convert the collection to an array & get the content from the first element
        application = collected.array()[0];
        let fileSearch = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1
        let appString = "" + application;
        var fs = require('fs')
        fs.appendFile(`./see/letters(${fileSearch}).txt`, appString + "\n", function (err){
          if (err) {

          } else {

          }
        })
        // Ask the next question
        console.log(application)
        return message.member.send("Got it, It was recieved")
        
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Good morning.

I was testing a little bit with your given code and I made some changes.

```
module.exports = {
name: 'ocean',
description: 'Takes User Input and saves it as Text file letters.txt',
execute(message, args) {
    let application = {}
    let filter = (message) => !message.author.bot;
    let options = {
        max: 1,
        time: 15000
    };
    message.member.send("Write something")
        .then(dm => {
            // After each question, we'll setup a collector on the DM channel
            return dm.channel.awaitMessages(filter, options)
        })
        .then(collected => {
            // Convert the collection to an array & get the content from the first element
            application = collected.array()[0].content;
            let fileSearch = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 1
            let appString = "";
            appString += application;
            var fs = require('fs')
            fs.appendFile(`./see/letters(${fileSearch}).txt`, appString + "\n", function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
            // Ask the next question
            console.log(application)
            return message.member.send("Got it, It was recieved")
        })
 }
}
```

First I want to say that `application = collected.array()[0].content;` works absolutely fine for me, every time I used it.

Anyways I changed `let appString = "" + application;` into

```
  let appString = "";
  appString += application;
```

What that makes is, it creates a variable `appString`, which is a string because we initialized it with `""`. In the second line we fill the currently empty string with the content we get from `application`. You could display it also like this: `appString = appString + application`. This works because `appString` is empty and gets the value of `application` into the empty string. Now the string isn't empty anymore and contains the content from `application`. This is a common way to fill a string.

I also changed your if else statement

```
fs.appendFile(`./see/letters(${fileSearch}).txt`, appString + "\n", function (err){
      if (err) {

      } else {

      }
    })
```

into

```
fs.appendFile(`./see/letters(${fileSearch}).txt`, appString + "\n", function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })
```

because you had the if else, but did nothing with it. Now if there is an error it gets printed out on your console.

I hope this is understable and helped with your problem.